# Why do I have different prompt when i log in differen shells

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I'm trying to create a user using shell script.

Here's what I tried:

```
password="tes7"
username="tes7"
pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
useradd -m -p "$pass" "$username"
```

That script should work, but the problem is, when i login from `ssh`, there is no detail at the first text, just `$`.

but if I do it manually like this, not with shell.

```
adduser username
Adding user `username' ...
Adding new group `username' (1001) ...
Adding new user `username' (1001) with group `username' ...
Creating home directory `/home/username' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password: fill this in manually
Retype new password: fill this in manually
```

When I login with `ssh`, I have a normal first prompt `tes5@ns-jazuly:~$`.

Comment: The second example applies some defaults that you are not setting with `useradd`. Particularly, `adduser` is using `/bin/bash` for the default shell but `useradd` defaults to `/bin/sh`. Add `-s /bin/bash` to your useradd command.

Comment: im tryng like this `useradd -m -p -s /bin/bash "$pass" "$username"` but i got help text..

Comment: @jordanm oh i got it, thanks.. write the answer with little explanation, so i can learn..

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know in witch shell you are you can always check it with

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

In bash(/bin/bash) the Prompt can be set changing the system variable PS1. Default this variable is:

```
echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$

you can change it for example to:
PS1='whatever'
```

But you can set it to whatever you like. If you feel cheeky you can also use ANSI/VT100 Control sequences.

In sh(/bin/sh) as you probably fear you can check it the prompt in the same way (I did that as root)

```
echo $PS1
#
```

as user you get **$**